# Computer wont boot after attempting to install ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I'm incredibly new to linux. Today I tried to install ubuntu on my desktop on dev/sda3 ext4 because it was the only option large enough after clicking install I got a message saying external 4 file system creation in p as partition failed and I tried to restart my computer after the install failed. I used unetbootin but the option doesn't pop up it just goes straight to infinite windows screen. The automatic repair says log file: \?\GLOBALROOT\Device\Harddiskvolume3\WINDOWS\System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt

Please help

Comment: That's what I tried to do I guess I just didnt word it properly

Comment: I even tried to reset my computer and it wont let me

Comment: So I used unetbootin and then tried to install it through the application of the desktop that says "install ubuntu" I went through the process as normal untill it skipped the portion of the installation process that allows you to choose from "erase disk and install ubuntu", "encrypt the new ubuntu installation for security" and "something else. It then automatically sent me to the screen you would see if you selected "somthing else" and I chose dev/sda3 ext 4 because it was the only option with enough space and was met with a message saying external 4 file system creation in partition failed

Comment: Then I tried to restart my pc to try again and It went to windows boot up and it wouldn't load after going to auto repair I was met with a message saying log file: \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\Harddiskvolume3\WINDOWS\System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt and then after going to troubleshoot reset pc I was met with a message that said there was a problem resetting your pc

Comment: So you have a partitioning problem, not an install problem, not a unetbootin problem, not a corrupt .iso. Show us an image of your partitioning scheme in Windows Disk Manager and also an image of your partitioning scheme in Gparted (it's in the "Try Ubuntu" environment). Questions about fixing your broken Windows install should be directed to a Windows support venue.

Comment: I dont think I can get there my pc wont go past windows loading screen

Comment: Advice: Fix your Windows first. You can install Ubuntu anytime.

Comment: Can I get advice on how to do that please

Comment: The best advice on Windows will be found on a Windows forum